# How to convert html elements into JSX?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

I have basically two questions.

1.) I have this basic reactjs component. How can I convert it into JSX?
I mean I want this code to look like reactjs style code.

2.) If I receive an array from backend like this

```
  [ '/parent-folder-1/child-folder-1/file1.jpg', '/parent-folder-1/child-folder-1/file2.jpg', '/parent-folder-1/child-folder-2/file3.jpg', '/parent-folder-2/child-folder-1/somefile.jpg' ]
```

How can I create nested object dynamically like the one shown in the code? I don't know how deep nested it could be.

Any help would be really appreciated......

```
class Filetree extends Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
          folders: [
            {
              type: "dir",
              name: "app",
              children: [
                {
                  type: "file",
                  name: "index.html"
                },
                {
                  type: "dir",
                  name: "js",
                  children: [
                    {
                      type: "file",
                      name: "main.js"
                    },
                    {
                      type: "file",
                      name: "misc.js"
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
        };
      }

      displayJsonTree(data) {
        var htmlRetStr = `<ul className='folder-container'>`;
        for (var key in data) {
          if (typeof data[key] === "object" && data[key] !== null) {
            htmlRetStr += this.displayJsonTree(data[key]);
            htmlRetStr += `</ul>`;
          } else if (data[key] === "dir") {
            htmlRetStr += `<li className='folder-item'> ${
              data["name"]
            } </li> <li className='folder-wrapper'>`;
          } else if (key === "name" && data["type"] !== "dir") {
            htmlRetStr += `<li className='file-item'> ${data["name"]} </li>`;
          }
        }
        return htmlRetStr;
      }

      render() {
        const { folders } = this.state;

        return <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.displayJsonTree(folders) }} />;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be a recursive technique. Use the object properties to determine what type of component to render, what it's props should be and what children it should have. You can use `React.createElement(...)` for that. Here's a snippet I did for recursively rendering a nested object. It'll be different depending on the shape of your data and various other things of course, but it's a starting point:

```
recursivelyRenderLinks(element) {
    const { children, ...props } = element;
    return React.createElement(
        TitleLink,
        props,
        children.length > 0 ?
        children.map((child) => this.recursivelyRenderLinks(child)) : null
    );
}
```

As for building that nested object from the array in the first place, that's another task you'd have to do first. Maybe split this into 2 separate questions.